# Angular Digest Authentication

Tags: angularjs, rest, digest-authentication

I'm trying to connect to a RESTFul API on a home automation server in my house (so massive security not required). When I try to connect with no credentials, I get:

```
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8176/devices/. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

The documentation says:

> Indigo uses "digest authentificaction" (not basic nor token)
>
> curl -X PUT --digest -u {username}:{password} -d value={value} http://{IPAddress}:8176/variables/{VariableToChange}
>
> curl -X PUT --digest -u admin:p@ssw0rd -d value=true http://{IPAddress}:8176/variables/Var1

To get a list of devices, I can use one of these 3:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8176/devices/
http://127.0.0.1:8176/devices.xml/
http://127.0.0.1:8176/devices.txt/
```

I'm at a total loss on how to pass the creeds. Here's my code so far:

```
 function DeviceController($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8176/devices/")
        .then(function (results) {
            //Success;
            console.log("Succss: " + results.status);
            $scope.devices = results.data;
        }, function (results) {
            //error
            console.log("Error: " + results.data + "; "
                                  + results.status);
            $scope.error = results.data;
        })
};
```

Can anyone point me in right direction?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: I think home automation server needs as much security as you can think of.

Comment: @icebreaker - not when it's on a secure local network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server has to be configured to accept [CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

**EDIT:**
It looks like your Indigo (don't know what it is) server is not the one serving your angular app. Please refer to your server's documentation on how to enable CORS.

As far as passing your credentials during your request, do:

```
$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8176/devices/",
    headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("admin:p@ssw0rd")},
})...
```

Comment: @gframontina thanks for reply. The server will eventually be apache on OS X. Rigght now I'm developing in Visual Studio so it's the asp web server. I found out I have to use digest authorization, can I just swap "Basic" for digest? (I'm guessing not :-(. Regards Mark

Comment: A quick search for angular + digest gave me a couple of modules that help dealing with the whole process: [https://github.com/PatrickHeneise/angular-digest-interceptor](https://github.com/PatrickHeneise/angular-digest-interceptor) and [https://github.com/tafax/angular-digest-auth](https://github.com/tafax/angular-digest-auth). I haven't used any of these, but they seem to make the task easier. As far as configuring your server to enable CORS, I don't have much experience in the .NET world, but I guarantee you this is possible. :-)

Comment: thanks for reply. I've turned off auth for now, but CORS is killing me. I'm using VS to develop, so my "web server" is the asp.net web server that VS starts for debugging. I added this to web.comfig, but still no luck <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />

Comment: Check these out: [enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html) and [asp.net/web-api](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors)

Comment: thanks for reply. I looked at the modules, they seem to be a client and server to add digest auth to your own server. I have no control over the server, but somehow have to use digest auth with the API I'm calling

Comment: So, I got it working. Turned out the server I was trying to connect to is written in CherrPy. All I had to do was add cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*' Obviously, I'll restrict it further once I finish testing. Thanks for all the help!